# What does "careening" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

I would like to know what is the meaning of the word "careening" in the [following context](http://erenow.com/common/sapiensbriefhistory/111.html):

> And yet the great debates of history are important because at least
>   the first generation of these gods would be shaped by the cultural
>   ideas of their human designers . Would they be created in the image of
>   capitalism , of Islam, or of feminism? The answer to this question
>   might send them "**careening**" in entirely different directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yuval Noah Harari's essay "*Humans have passed their expiry date*" posits that because of genetic engineering, a new generation of super humans will arise.

In your selection, Harari refers to these super humans as "gods" and he makes reference to the Human Enhancement question: What will these new being be like?

He then describes how some of the pull-me-push-you forces which may determine this outcome can cause wildly differing results: **careening**.

> to careen

is to move violently with changes in direction.

> The ball **careened** from side to side during the pin ball game.

[image]
<sub>(source: [arcadehits.net](http://popotte.arcadehits.net/RollingStones_F2.jpg))</sub>

> The bobsled **careened** off the wall coming out of the turn.

[image]

Harari is saying the possible outcomes for the future humans may cause wildly different and extreme results depending on who is making the final decisions.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might be a typing mistake as I hadn't heard of the word and I am an native speaker in England.  However, a quick Google search reveals *careening* to mean

> verb gerund or present participle: careening
>
> 1. turn (a ship) on its side for cleaning, caulking, or repair.
> 2. NORTH AMERICAN move swiftly and in an uncontrolled way.
>
> "an electric golf cart careened around the corner"

As this definition tells us, this is a North American word for *careering* which we use in England for the same meaning.

Comment: What might "them" in the last sentence mean?

Comment: Without knowing what the text says in full I cannot give a definite answer but from what you have given, *them* refers to the 'human designers of the gods'.